# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "blob:url

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, google-chrome

Estoy cargando un pdf en un modal con PDFobject, este me carga correctamente el archivo pdf en el modal, pero en la consola de Chrome me indica el siguiente mensaje
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "blob:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi jquery

```
    $(document).on('click', '.verCurriculum', function(){ // ver curriculum

      $('#modal-verPDF').modal('show');

      var $modalPDF = $('#verPDF');
      var id_profesor = $(this).data("id");
      var view_html = '';
      var url = "{{ url('descargar_curriculum_pdf') }}/"+id_profesor;
      var token = $(this).attr('id');
      var datos = new FormData();
      datos.append("token",token);

      var url_profesor = "{{ url('verProfesor') }}/"+id_profesor;

      $.get(url_profesor, function (r) {
        var edata = $.parseJSON(r);

        $('#titulo-modal-pdf').html('Curriculum de ' + edata.nombre + ' ' + edata.apellidos);

        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000
        })

        if(edata.curriculum.length == 0){

          Toast.fire({
            type: 'info',
            title: 'El profesor ' + edata.nombre + ' ' + edata.apellidos + ' no tiene curriculum en el sistema'
          })

        }else{
          $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:"GET",
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            xhrFields: {
              responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function(regreso){
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(regreso);
              a.href = url;
              a.view = 'curriculum_'+id_profesor+'.pdf';
              // a.click();
              // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
              PDFObject.embed(url, '#verPDF');
            }
          });
        }  
      });
    });
```

Tambien probe sin PDFObject, coloque un `<object class="PDFdoc" id="verPDF" width="100%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" data=""></object>` en el cual mediante jquery le cargaba la url al data y funcionaba correctamente, pero aparece igualmente el mensaje en la consola.

Igualmente probe con iframe, pero es lo mismo.

Comment: Posiblemente sea el mismo problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7998/descargar-pdf-en-respuesta-a-una-petici%C3%B3n-ajax

Comment: Elimino el comentario anterior, el `responseType:` no puede ser `"application/pdf"`. Debería de ser en el `contentType: "application/pdf"`, pero mucho me temo que te ocurrirá lo mismo que en la pregunta que te he linkeado anteriormente.

Comment: Intente hacerlo con xhr como la solución de la otra pregunta, pero ocurre exactamente lo mismo, por lo que lei en la pregunta que me enviaste, es problema de ajax y blobs mediante ajax... lo que no se, es si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo

Comment: Añadele la cabecera en la parte del servidor (si puedes modificarlo) `header("Content-type:application/pdf");` (en el método al que apunta el ajax)